# Can you use an email address as the login with Active Directory and SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

Assuming email addresses are all different, so not from one or two single email suffixes.

I know there is UPN login, but I believe that to be with predefined UPN Suffixes, not 1000s of unique ones.

There is also ADFS type stuff.

Comment: How can we do this with AD?   So accounts are stored in AD, but when logging in the user would enter jsmith@yahoo.com or jsmith@whatever.com, not necessarily the same suffix.   This would map to an AD account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use email address as the login normally in interanet you can use Your exchange email address associated with your AD user id.
in extranet app scenarios you can use open id based authentication or windows live id